# Snakemake: merging inputs with different suffixes to same-suffix output

Tags: python, snakemake

Okay, I've been trying all day to solve this, to no avail... I am working with downloading and analysing RNA-sequencing data, and my analysis incorporates public datasets that come in two flavours: single-end reads and paired-end reads. In essence, every raw file that my workflow start to work on can either be a single file named `{sample}.fastq.gz` or two files, named `{sample}_1.fastq.gz` and `{sample}_2.fastq.gz`, respectively.

I have all the samples and their read layouts (and some other info) in a metadata file which I parse with pandas into a dataframe. I need to be able to give parameters to my scripts (here simply abstracted to `touch {output}`) in order for them to perform their function depending on the read layout (they are all bash scripts using command line software like `sratools` and `STAR`). What I want to achieve is something along the following `snakemake` pseudocode:

```
# Metadata in a pandas dataframe
metadata = data.frame(SAMPLES, LAYOUTS, ...)

# Function for retrieving metadata
def get_metadata(sample, column):
    result = metadata.loc[metadata['sample'] == sample][column].values[0]
    return result

# Rules
rule all:
    input:
        expand('{sample}.bam', sample = SAMPLES)

rule: download:
    output:
        '{sample}.fastq.gz' for 'SINGLE' in metadata[LAYOUT],
        '{sample}_1.fastq.gz' for 'PAIRED' in metadata[LAYOUT]
    params:
        layout = lambda wildcards:
            get_metadata(wildcards.sample, layout_col)
    shell:
        'touch {output}'

rule align:
    input:
        '{sample}.fastq.gz' for 'SINGLE' in metadata[LAYOUT],
        '{sample}_1.fastq.gz' for 'PAIRED' in metadata[LAYOUT]
    params:
        layout = lambda wildcards:
            get_metadata(wildcards.sample, layout_col)
    output:
        '{sample}.bam'
    shell:
        'touch {output}'
```

In all code variations I have tried so far I either create ambiguous rules, create single-end reads for paired-end IDs (and vice versa) or it all just fails. I have come up with two very unsatisfactory solutions:

1. Have two entirely separate workflows, one working on the single-end inputs and the other for the paired-end, requiring the user to manually start both
2. Have a single workflow that separates the read layouts by adding a prefix `'single'`/`'paired'` for every file in the workflow (*i.e.* `single/{sample}.bam`, etc.)

The first is unsatisfactory because the user has to start two different workflows, and the second because it adds a level of input data abstraction that is not present in the output data (since the output `.bam`-files are created regardless of the input read layouts through options in the sub-scripts I have).

Does somebody have a better idea as to how to achieve this? If it's unclear as to what I'm after I'd be happy to elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [function as input](http://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#functions-as-input-files):

```
def align_input(wildcards):
   # Check if wildcards.sample is paired end or single end
   # If single end, return '{sample}.fastq.gz'.format(wildcards.sample)
   # Else, return '{sample}_1.fastq.gz'.format(wildcards.sample) and
   #              '{sample}_2.fastq.gz'.format(wildcards.sample) as list

rule align:
    input: align_input
    output: '{sample}.bam'
    shell: ...
```

One thing is that you have your align rule written where the input lists every fastq file for all your samples. You want to write your rules so that the input has the fastq file(s) for just a single sample, and the command to align that single sample. The wildcard {sample} means that it will apply that rule for all the samples you have, one at a time. You should probably do something similar with your download rule.

Another solution would be to pre-download all the files, outside of the workflow, then you can use two separate align rules:

```
rule align_se:
    input: '{sample}.fastq.gz'
    output: '{sample}.bam'

rule align_pe:
    input: '{sample}_1.fastq.gz', '{sample}_2.fastq.gz'
    output: '{sample}.bam'
```

Since the fastq files already exist, snakemake will see for each sample that only one of the rules can be applied because the input files are missing for the other rule, and it has no rule to create them.

Comment: Ok, that's great for the `align` rule, but what about `download`? I can use a similar function and create the files needed, but since I can only use functions for inputs it doesn't help, as the files don't exist before the download is complete. If I could use a function as output it'd be okay... Any way around this? (And I can't just use `expand()`, as I need to access the wildcards for the `params` even in the `download` rule).

Comment: Having two download rules, one for se one for pe, should work.

Comment: Exactly how do you mean? I've tried making two separate rules for each (using `expand` to create input files for each), but then I can't successfully merge them into the alignment rule; when using the wildcard `{sample}` it tries to find both types of fastq files for both read layouts, rather than separating them.

Comment: I mean pretty much exactly how I have the two rules for align in my answer, but the inputs are outputs instead. Can you post what your snakemake file looks like after making them two separate rules? There may be some other issue causing the error.

Comment: I have done like you showed, except I have changed the file names for the paired-end fastq files to `.fastq_1.gz` and `.fastq_2.gz` (otherwise `{sample}.fastq.gz` will map to both se/pe reads). This actually works when I am just running the workflow locally, but not when I run it on a cluster, for some odd reason. I am just submitting the jobs using a snakemake wrapper, along with a `cluster.yaml` file. When I do this, it somehow messes things up, and I don't know why... I'm currently trying to basically perform two separate workflows for se/pe reads with a loop, hiding it from the user.